Sorting the result of a ping command in three categories using a batch script
I'm trying to run a ping command and sorting based on "online", "offline" and "expired". I tried using find and findstr but I only seem to be able to sort through 2 options.
I currently have this:
ping -n 1 %ip% | find "TTL"
if errorlevel 1 set error= offline
if errorlevel 0 | find "expired"
if errorlevel 0 set error=expired
else set error=online

I'm guessing this doesn't work because the third line doesn't know where to search for "expired"?
Any help would be really appreciated.
An online pc returns this:
Pinging pcName [ip] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ip: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=125
Reply from ip: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=125
Reply from ip: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=125
Reply from ip: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=125

Ping statistics for ip:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms

An offline pc returns this:
Pinging pcName [ip] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for ip:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

And an expired pc returns this:
Pinging pcName [ip] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ip: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from ip: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from ip: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from ip: TTL expired in transit.

Ping statistics for ip:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),


Please start by running example pings which output the lines you are trying to target, (containing expired and TTL), and copy and paste that output into code boxes within your question.

Updated the question.

You can't filter data twice (I mean, you can filter filtered output again (serial), but you can't use filters in parallel. Workaround: redirect to a file and process that file three times (to work on consistent data).

@MatissePriem, I have removed your most recent [Edit]. We do not want updates on your chosen solution/workaround in the question itself. You are free however to submit an answer to your own question.

@Stephan; You can "reuse" a file redirected into a block via several find commands (in "parallel"). See my answer below. This does not work with findstr

@Aacini: interesting. Nevertheless: you need a file (you can't redirect from a command), but when using a file, just three find or findstr commands are more intuitive to read.

@Aacini's answer works and is technically correct, but hard to read and to troubleshoot without a lot of experience in cmd/batch. And more importantly: it is language-dependent.
ping is language-dependent, and I always try to find a language-independent solution (not always possible though). As with ping, the constant through all languages is the string TTL (never translated).
Your three example lines can easily be distinguished:
Request timed out.                       none of the search strings = status = "offline" (as default)
Reply from ip: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=125 searchstring "TTL=" = overwrite status with "online"
Reply from ip: TTL expired in transit.   searchstring "TTL " = overwrite status with "expired"

The code is quite intuitive and easy to read:
@echo off
setlocal 
ping -4 -n 1 %ip% >ping.txt
set "status=offline"
>nul find "TTL " ping.txt && set "status=expired"
>nul find "TTL=" ping.txt && set "status=online"
echo %ip% is %status%

I didn't ever experience an "expired", but based on the output in your question, my solution should work just fine.
And more important: this is language-independent.
(I added -4 because the output using IPv6 is different - not important if you use an IPv4 Address, but will bite you when using something like "google.com" and both IPv4 AND IPv6 are enabled)

This works perfectly, thank you so much!

This is not an answer, merely a very important remark.
Your pseudo-code contains the following:
if errorlevel 1 set error= offline
if errorlevel 0 | find "expired"

You need to realise that both cases might happen: you launch your "ping"-request, and the errorlevel equals 1. As a result of that, the variable error will get the value offline.
Then again you check the errorlevel being zero and it is very well possible that this is true, because this time it will not be the errorlevel of the "ping" request, but the errorlevel of the variable assignment set error=offline!

also if errorlevel n works as "If errorlevel is n or higher", so the second if gets executed anyway. Just the |find doesn't make any sense here. It's not a valid command and the output of ping (which I guess OP is trying to "refilter") is long gone at this point.

You almost have it!  ;)
ping -n 1 %ip% > ping.txt

< ping.txt (
   find "TTL"
   if errorlevel 1 (
      set error=offline
   ) else (
      find "expired"
      if not errorlevel 1 (
         set error=expired
      ) else (
         set error=online
      )
   )
) > NUL

